# Cloning row with independent values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a few issues with something.  I have the following two tables

```
<table id="customFields1" class="table table-bordered table-hover additionalMargin alignment">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
        <th>Some Title</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label class="subjectline" for="User1">User NOC M1</label></td>
            <td id="slLabel">SL_A</td>
            <td id="slInput"><input type="text" name="slOptions[User][NOC M1]" class="form-control" id="User1"></td>
            <td><a class="addCF" href="javascript:void(0);">+ additional user</a></td>
        </tr> 

    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="customFields2" class="table table-bordered table-hover additionalMargin alignment">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
        <th>Some Title</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label class="subjectline" for="User1">User NOC M1</label></td>
            <td id="slLabel">SL_A</td>
            <td id="slInput"><input type="text" name="slOptions[User][NOC M1]" class="form-control" id="User1"></td>
            <td><a class="addCF" href="javascript:void(0);">+ additional user</a></td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Both of the have an addCF button.  This is used to add a new row to the table.  This is achieved through this

```
$(function() {
    alp = "A";
    regexp = /[_A]+$/;

    $(".addCF").click(function(){
        alp = (alp.substring(0,alp.length-1)+String.fromCharCode(alp.charCodeAt(alp.length-1)+1));
        var clone = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);

        var inputOrgLabel =  $("td:nth-child(2)", clone).html();
        inputOrgLabel = inputOrgLabel.replace(regexp,'');
        $("td:nth-child(2)", clone).html(inputOrgLabel+'_'+alp);

        $("td:first-child", clone).empty();
        $("td:last-child", clone).html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a>');
        clone.insertAfter($(this).closest('table').find('tr:last'));
    });
    $("table.table").on('click','.remCF',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Everything appears to work besides one thing.  If I add a new row, I change the label SL_A to SL_B.  Every row added has the next letter of the alphabet added to the end of it.  This is working, but if I add a row in table 1, making it SL_B, and then add a row in table 2, the row in table 2 has SL_C.  Each of the incrementations of letters should be independent, so the second row in table two should also have SL_B.

Is this possible?  I have set up a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zwf9njr/15/) to demonstrate

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made an array for holding your data in alp and changed accordingly. Here i ma getting the index of the clicked button to use that index as the index of the apl array.

```
$(function() {
    alp = [];
    $.each($('.addCF'), function(i,v) {
        alp[i] = "A";
    })

    regexp = /[_A]+$/;

    $(".addCF").click(function(e){
    index = $('.addCF').index($(this));
        alp[index] = (alp[index].substring(0,alp[index].length-1)+String.fromCharCode(alp[index].charCodeAt(alp[index].length-1)+1)); 
        var clone = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);

        var inputOrgLabel =  $("td:nth-child(2)", clone).html();
        inputOrgLabel = inputOrgLabel.replace(regexp,'');
        $("td:nth-child(2)", clone).html(inputOrgLabel+'_'+alp[index]);

        $("td:first-child", clone).empty();
        $("td:last-child", clone).html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a>');
        clone.insertAfter($(this).closest('table').find('tr:last'));
    });
    $("table.table").on('click','.remCF',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Note: You have to manage code for remove, as it is not resetting the value.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.  There is one problem I see though.  I do not know how many tables there will be as they will be added dynamically based on some other data.  This solution accomodates two tables perfectly, but only two.  Is there any way to handle X amount of tables?  Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now it will work as you required :)